# Why is the MTU different for With Response vs Without Response?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

On iOS when I request the MTU I get different values for `.withoutResponse` vs `.withResponse`. I realize it could be different since the function takes that parameter, but why is it different?

Here's on device (BLE 4.2):

```
(lldb) po peripheral.maximumWriteValueLength(for: .withoutResponse)
182

(lldb) po peripheral.maximumWriteValueLength(for: .withResponse)
512
```

On another device (BLE 5) I get:

```
(lldb) po peripheral.maximumWriteValueLength(for: .withoutResponse)
509

(lldb) po peripheral.maximumWriteValueLength(for: .withResponse)
512
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write Without Response is directly related to the MTU. (MTU - 3).

When you use `writeWithResponse`, iOS can either perform a Write With Response (max value length is MTU - 3), or a "Write Long Characteristic Values", which uses several ATT transactions to write the value. In the latter case the only restricting factor is the maximum length of a characteristic value, which is set to 512 bytes by the standard.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a reference I can read more into? (or section in the BLE Spec) What exactly about specifying the "response" makes the difference.

Comment: Just read the GATT chapter, for example section 4.9.4.